# Entity Frame Work Delete entity optimistic error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, optimistic-concurrency

I have project where two table of it has a one to one relation. Suppose they are named `Media` and `Movie`

In the model I designed that `Movie` Inherit from `Media` as a movie is a type of media and has all the properties of media.

My problem is when I want to remove Movie I use entity like this :Model.Media.remove(Movie)

When saving changes I get this error :

*"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."*

The solution that I found so far,  are all about updating ,but i don't have any problem with updating.I guess the problem is for inheritance ,but i am not sure.

Comment: What is your code for deletion?

Comment: context.deleteobject(Entity) ; Context.savechanges();

Comment: Do you have only one context or more? Are there other processes updating the DB at the same time? Please show complete, short code that demonstrates the error.